# How to catch ng-keypress/ $event when clicked outside of div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, event-handling

I am building a sudoku game in AngularJS. What I want to achieve is to catch ng-keypress even if I click outside of the div on the page. Take a look at http://sudoku.com/ for example if you select a cell and then click wherever you want on the page and after that, if you click on any number still it is going to change that number in the cell. How can I achieve that?

Please take a look at the HTML code below:

```
<table class="sudoku-board" ng-init="getSudoku()" id="sudoku"
                                   ng-class="{'paused': visible}">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="sudoku-row" ng-repeat="sudoku in sudokuGrid track by $index"
                                        ng-init="row = $index">
                                        <td class="sudoku-col sudoku-cell" ng-repeat="number in sudoku track by $index"
                                            ng-init="col = $index" ng-class="{'highlight': colSelected === col || isHighlight(row, col) || rowSelected === row,
                                            'highlight-number':getValue === number.substring(0, 1), 'selected':isSelected === ((row*10) + col), 'paused': visible}"
                                            ng-click="selectedCell(row, col)"
                                            ng-keydown="insertNum($event, row, col);" tabindex="1">
                                            <span class="cell-value"
                                                  ng-class="{'empty': number === null || number.charAt(number.length-1) === '!', 'default': number !== null, 'paused': visible}"
                                                  ng-bind="number.substring(0, 1)"></span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

On ng-keydown I am firing this function:

```
// handle inserted value
$scope.insertNum = function (e, row, col, number) {
    console.log("Number: " + number);
    $scope.selectedCol = col; // get selected column
    $scope.selectedRow = row; // get selected row
    console.log(e);
    if (e !== undefined) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode; // assign key & char code
        if ((keyCode < 49 || ((keyCode > 57 && keyCode < 97) || keyCode > 105)) && (keyCode !== 8 && keyCode !== 46))
            return false; // if clicked button/ event is not a number or delete/ backspace button -> return false

        if (e.currentTarget.children[0].classList[2] === 'empty') // check if clicked cell is empty
            if (keyCode === 8 || keyCode === 46) { // if clicked delete/ backspace remove the current value
                e.currentTarget.children[0].innerHTML = null;
                $scope.sudokuGrid[row][col] = null;
                $(e.target).removeClass("incorrect");
                $(e.target).removeClass("correct");
                $scope.handleErrorClass();
                $scope.getValue = false;
            }
            else { // when number is clicked
                e.currentTarget.children[0].innerHTML = e.key; //  insert that number in the cell
                $scope.sudokuGrid[row][col] = e.key + "!";
                $scope.checkCurrentNumber(row, col);
                $scope.getCurrentNumber(row, col);

                // if inserted number is correct add class
                if (e.key === $scope.sudokuGridSolved[row][col]) {
                    console.log("Correct");
                    $(e.target).removeClass("incorrect");
                    $(e.target).addClass("correct");
                }
                // add incorrect class if inserted number is not correct
                else {
                    console.log("Incorrect");
                    $(e.target).removeClass("correct");
                    $(e.target).addClass("incorrect");
                }
                //$scope.sudokuGrid[row][col] = e.key;
            }
    }
    else {
        if (number !== null && $("tr:eq(" + $scope.selectedRow + ") td:eq(" + $scope.selectedCol + ") span").hasClass("empty")) {
            $("tr:eq(" + $scope.selectedRow + ") td:eq(" + $scope.selectedCol + ") span").html(number);
            $scope.sudokuGrid[row][col] = number + "!";
            $scope.checkCurrentNumber(row, col);
            $scope.getCurrentNumber(row, col);

            // if inserted number is correct add class
            if ($scope.getValue === $scope.sudokuGridSolved[row][col]) {
                console.log("Correct");
                $("tr:eq(" + $scope.selectedRow + ") td:eq(" + $scope.selectedCol + ")").removeClass("incorrect");
                $("tr:eq(" + $scope.selectedRow + ") td:eq(" + $scope.selectedCol + ")").addClass("correct");
            }
            // add incorrect class if inserted number is not correct
            else {
                console.log("Incorrect!");
                $("tr:eq(" + $scope.selectedRow + ") td:eq(" + $scope.selectedCol + ")").removeClass("correct");
                $("tr:eq(" + $scope.selectedRow + ") td:eq(" + $scope.selectedCol + ")").addClass("incorrect");
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.checkForIdenticalValues();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is because `ng-keydown` is on the `<td>` tag so the function will only be called when it's the currently focused element, but it sounds like you want to respond to the key down event from anywhere on the page.

You can do this by using `ng-keydown` on the body tag instead of the `<td>`, then make the function broadcast an event that can be listened to from the sudoku component to run the insertNum logic. Like so:

```html
<body ng-keydown="onMyKeydownEvent($event)">
```

Then you bound the function on the `$rootScope` within `run()` to broadcast an event.

```js
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.onMyKeydownEvent = function(e) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast("MyKeydownEvent", e);
  };
});
```

After that add the listener to your component.

```js
$scope.$on("MyKeydownEvent", function(e) {
  // insertNum logic goes here.
});
```

You will also need to make some adjustments to the logic as things like `e.currentTarget` and `$scope.selectedCol = col;` `$scope.selectedRow = row;` will no longer work as expected. Instead the `ng-click="selectedCell(row, col)"` on the `<td>` tag should be responsible for setting the required cell data into the scope so that it can be used within the event.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it now and let you know of the outcome

Comment: Okay, so I get the $event to console.log which works fine - do you have any idea how can I catch the key or the value which is pressed?

Comment: In `$scope.$on("MyKeydownEvent", function(e) {  }` you can use `e.keyCode` to get the key.

Comment: @user13289818 any success?

Comment: just a question - I have an input field on the website, and when I write something within the input field it also is written within the sudoku cell. Any idea how to not send the events from the input field to the sudoku cell?

Comment: You can add a flag tell if the input field is focused. `$scope.skipEvent = false`. Then on the input field add `<input ng-focus="skipEvent=true" ng-blur="skipEvent=false" type="text" />`. Now in `$scope.$on("MyKeydownEvent", function(e) {` you can check to is if `$scope.skipEvent` is `true`, if it is return: `if ($scope.skipEvent)  return;`.